# Problem with gerunds

Tags: gerunds

I'm a non-native English speaker and have recently come across a phrase, also written by a non-native English speaker, that puzzled me:

> Automatic creating tasks

(this is the name of a software feature that creates multiple tasks based on some pre-defined values (you don't have to manually create each of them))

It seems 100% incorrect, but I can't figure out why. Or is it me who is incorrect thinking the prase is wrong? Can someone give me a hint?

My suggestion is that the gerund can't be modified by an adjective and followed by a noun...

Comment: Are "creating tasks" a type of task that are created automatically?

Comment: No, it is a function that creates tasks automatically, e.g. you click a button, and a series of tasks is created based on some pre-defined values.

Comment: Why would you expect a phrase "written by a non-native English speaker" to make any sense?

Comment: In that case, you are best off recasting the sentence to avoid confusion. Using the adjective in this construction sounds strange not because it's ungrammatical (see: "incomplete passing plays", "cold running water"), but because it causes the reader to read "creating tasks" as a noun phrase, which sounds unnatural.

Comment: Would 'Autimatic cresting tusks' be 170% incorrect?

Comment: @Robusto: I think the question is legitimate for ELU. If OP had been asking *which is correct*, that might be a different matter. But the issue of ***why*** [most/all of us?] would probably require/prefer to include **of** in OP's context seems subtle (or perhaps just *idiomatic*) to me. How come we mostly *wouldn't* want it in, say, *"His watching **of** porn movies annoys me"*?

Answer (score 4):

The gerund can't be modified by an adjective (use an adverb for that), but it can be followed by a noun.
So this should be either

> automatically creating tasks

or

> automatic creation of tasks

Comment: What if "creating tasks" is meant to be taken as a noun phrase, as opposed to "deleting tasks"? You'd want to specify that creating tasks occur automatically and not that the creation of (all) tasks occur automatically.

Comment: Glorfindel, so, "His hard working", for example, is incorrect?

Comment: @PassingBy: *hard* is an adverb there, but it's one that comes after verbs, so it should be *his working hard.*  (Although *his hard working* might be marginally acceptable.) Note the difference between *"he works hard"* and *"he hardly works"*.

Comment: @PeterShor What if "hard" was an adjective here? Or, say, "His _persistent_ working", that would be incorect because gerund cannot follow adjectives, right?

Comment: @PassingBy: gerunds ***with direct objects*** cannot follow adjectives. So *automatic targeting* is fine, and *targeting cancer cells* is fine, but **automatic targeting cancer cells* is incorrect. You have to use *automatic targeting of cancer cells* or *automatically targeting cancer cells*.

Comment: If "creating tasks" is already used in other parts of the application, it might be thought of as a feature name, and thus treated as a noun. However, a native English speaker would still identify this as stilted, even if it's technically acceptable. "Automatic task creation" seems the most natural to me.

Comment: @PeterShor, could you please give an example of a gerund with indirect object?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is wrong.

This is a proper alternative:

[***"the automated creation of"***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20atomatic%20creation%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22the%20automated%20creation%20of%22) [tasks]

See examples of it at Google Books.

***"the automatic creation of"*** [tasks]

is also correct and more frequent.

Other possibilities:

***"the automated task creation"***

***"the automatic task creation"***